# Joint density function problem

Tags: probability, integration

I have a joint density function of Random Variables X and Y given by:

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2e^{-x}e^{-2y} & 0<x<\infty, 0<y<\infty \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

And I'm supposed to find P{ X < Y }. This is a worked example and the solution is:

\begin{align}
P\{X<Y\} &= \iint_{(x,y):x<y} 2e^{-x}e^{-2y}dx\,dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^y 2e^{-x} e^{-2y}dx\,dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty 2e^{-2y}(1-e^{-y})\,dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty 2e^{-2y}dy - \int_0^\infty 2e^{-3y} dy \\
&= 1 - \frac23 \\
&= \frac13
\end{align}

I don't understand why the boundaries of the outer integration are 0 to infinity. Shouldn't it be from x to infinity?

Comment: It makes sense if you graph the region integrated over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joint density function "lives" in the first quadrant. We want the probability that $X\lt Y$. **Draw the line** $y=x$.

Let $K$ be the part of the first quadrant that is **above** the line $y=x$. The probability that $X\lt Y$ is the probability that the pair $(X,Y)$ lands in the region $K$. Formally, our probability is 
$$\iint_K 2e^{-x}e^{-2y}\,dx\,dy.$$
To evaluate, we express the double integral as an *iterated* integral.

The person solving the problem chose to integrate first with respect to $x$. Then $x$ travels from $0$ to $y$, and, after that, $y$ travels freely from $0$ to $\infty$.

I would have done it another way, integrating first with respect to $y$. Then $y$ travels from $x$ to $\infty$, and then $x$ travels freely from $0$ to $\infty$. We end up with a slightly simpler expression.

**Remark:** One way to see that the outer integral cannot be from $x$ to $\infty$ is that the ultimate answer is a pure *number*: it cannot involve $x$.

Comment: I don't understand completely but this gave me some intuition the problem.

Comment: It helps to have a fair bit of "double integral" experience. The critical thing is to draw a picture, identify the region $K$. It is a sort of infinite triangle. If we integrate first with respect to $x$ (not a good idea, but that's what they did) then for any $y$ we first "add up" (integrate)  from $x=0$ to $x=y$. Then we add up the result over all $y$.